# Can someone recommend me a backup solution that can be used for an educational institution?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup

The online university where I study is constantly experiencing data loss, including students’ files and literature, so I want to recommend them an effective solution.

Comment: @Alvar... maybe, let's see... Elizabet, what are your requirements?  Is this just a personal solution or for a number of students?? How are the files stored??? Please elaborate...

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are using Linux in your system, in the scenario presented the best would be a userless solution. I would do it using a backup server (simple fileserver, nothing fancy), and `rsync` over ssh. The `rsync` would run from cron.

Steps:
Set up ssh keys (to can use cron passwordless):

```
cd ~/.ssh  
ssh-keygen -t dsa
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub user@yourserver.com
```

Test it with `ssh user@yourserver.com`. It sould not require a password anymore.
Now you can use the `rsync -atvz ~/local-directory/ user@youserver.com:remote-directory/` command in `crontab`.